# Usar NotificationManager em uma classe que não é Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou tendo um probleminha e não estou conseguindo evoluir. O problema é o seguinte: Tenho um Fragment no meu app, e quero disparar um notificação a partir dele. A linha em que estou tendo problemas é esta: `NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

O erro está no `getSystemService()`, a IDE me diz que "O método `getSystemService(String)` é undefined para o tipo `MinhaClasseFragment` "

Já tentei pegar e passar contextos, até usar um `Context` recebendo `getActivity()` e nada.

Procurei pela web e não achei nada que me ajudasse.
O que fazer?

Comment: NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  

Tente fazer assim direto.

Comment: Caramba, como eu não pensei nisso!

Obrigado, Helder. Ainda sou rookie no Android rs

Comment: @Helder poste sua resposta em forma de resposta. Assim o OP poderá aceitá-la e todos saberão que o problema está resolvido. Além disso você pode ganhar reputação por isso.

Comment: @Helder Sim, faça isso :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Tente fazer assim direto.

Comment: Brigadão mais uma vez.